# Syntax question on reduce part of RavenDB index, average calculation

Tags: average, ravendb, reduce, ravendb-studio

I am struggling with the correct syntax for an averaging column. What I have - from RavenDB Studio editor:

Map:

```
from area in docs.Level5_AdministrativeAreas
select new 
{
     area.NAME_4,
     totalPrice = area.pricePerSquareMetre,
     areaCount = 1,
     priceAverage = 0
}
```

Reduce:

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.NAME_4 } into g
select new 
{
   NAME_4 = g.Key.NAME_4,
   totalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice),
   areaCount = g.Sum(x => x.areaCount),
   priceAverage = totalPrice / areaCount
}
```

Count and total price are being calculated correctly, but I don't know how to reference `totalPrice` and `areaCount`.

Is an extra select block required ? I tried "g.totalPrice" & "g.priceAverage", but it's not recognised.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Reduce part needs to be like this :

**Reduce**:

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.NAME_4 } into g
let theCount = g.Sum(x => x.areaCount)
let theTotal = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice)
select new 
{
   NAME_4 = g.Key.NAME_4,
   totalPrice = theTotal,
   areaCount = theCount ,
   priceAverage = theTotal / theCount 
}
```

=> Read section [Common Pitfalls with MapReduce Indexes](https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/11-mapreduce-and-aggregations-in-ravendb#common-pitfalls-with-mapreduce-indexes)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not ideal, but this works (talk about not seeing the forest for the trees...)

```
priceAverage = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice) / g.Sum(x => x.areaCount)
```